# Writing/modifying files in sd card's public storage in Android?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

How can I get a list of the files stored in the SD card's external storage (music, pictures...), modify a file's contents and overwrite the old file in Android 5.0+.

Comment: External storage has little to do with an SD card. Please clarify whether you are referring to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: Removable storage. The music I have on my sd card for example. **Not** my app's private space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not strictly possible.

The closest you are going to get is:

- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to get the user to choose a document tree. The user can choose whatever the user wants. It does not have to be removable storage — it could be external storage, Google Drive, etc.
- Given the `Uri` that you get back from the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` activity, wrap it in a `DocumentFile` using `fromTreeUri()`.
- From there, use `DocumentFile` a bit like you would use `File`, using `listFiles()` and `isDirectory()` recursively to walk the document tree.
- For whatever content you want to modify, use `getUri()` on the `DocumentFile` to get the `Uri` for that piece of content, use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to read in the content, and use `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to write out your modified content.

Comment: @VasilKalchev: I have no idea, as I have never written one. Amaze is open source; you might see if they have support for removable storage and what they do.

Comment: FileManagers will not use DocumentFile to list files as it is much to slow. Instead they will use DocumentsContract.

Comment: @greenapps: `DocumentFile` is merely a wrapper around `DocumentsContract`.